# rspec showing error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rspec

Rspec is showing following error message when i run `bundle exec rake`. But the tests are running fine. Is this something to worry about or is it safe to ignore??

> /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby
>   -I/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib
>   /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec
>   --pattern spec/**{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb failed

```
spec_helper.rb

# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    expectations.syntax = [:expect]
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
    mocks.verify_doubled_constant_names = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!
  config.expose_dsl_globally = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end
```

**rake.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle exec rspec`?

Comment: no errors shows up if I run bundle exec rspec but bundle exec rake is showing errors.. Is it because  I used the wrong command? Because I found it on a book..

Comment: Could you please edit your post and including our `rakefile`, your `spec_helper` and your `rails_helper`? Also, in which folder are your tests in your Rails app?

Comment: @born4new updated..the spec_helper is the only one I changed..But Even with the default settings its showing this error

Comment: Question now: Are your tests in a folder called `spec` or `test`? Just so you know, it should be `spec` when using rspec.

Comment: its in spec folder..bundle exec rspec works without showing errors

Comment: As long as you can launch your specs, I wouldn't worry too much about this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely safe yes, I personally only use `bundle exec rspec`, rarely do I use rake for this.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `rake` to run spec.

If there are failed specs, then you will have the `...failed` message.

Or your coverage is lower than the minimum coverage if you have set the

`minimum_coverage your_target_num` of SimpleCov.